# Update document record to the corresponding tag aware shard db

Tags: mongodb, tags, sharding

Does Mongo move the newly updated document in tag aware shard db set up to the correct shard?

We have the following set up with MongoDb ver. 2.4.6 and using C# driver 1.8.3, it did not return the expected result for the update scenario on tag aware sharding.  Please assist to review the following scenario and let us know whether MongoDb is capable of this.

We have the following set up for the experiement:

```
//use the default 'test' database
db = db.getSiblingDB('test');`

//Add shards
sh.addShard( "shard0001.local:27017" );
sh.addShard( "shard0002.local:27017" );

//Enable sharding for the database,
sh.enableSharding("test");

//Enable sharding for a collection,
sh.shardCollection("test.persons", { "countryCode": 1, "_id": 1 } );

//Add shard tags,
sh.addShardTag("shard0001", "USA");
sh.addShardTag("shard0002", "JPN");

//Tag shard key ranges, 
sh.addTagRange("test.persons", { countryCode: 0 }, { countryCode: 1 }, "USA");
sh.addTagRange("test.persons", { countryCode: 1 }, { countryCode: 2 }, "JPN");
```

Then we execute the following script for the initial data population:

```
//MongoDB sharding test,
db = db.getSiblingDB('test')

//Load data
//USA: countryCode 0
//JPN: countryCode 1

for (var i=0; i < 1000, i++) {
    db.persons.insert( { name: "USA-" + i, countryCode: 0 } )
          db.persons.insert( { name: "JPN-" + i, countryCode: 1 } )
```

At this point, we have 1000 records for each shard, 1000 records for USA country code in shard0001 and 1000 records for JPN in shard0002.

From C#, we have the following pseudo code:

```
collection.insert( 1 document of countryCode=0)
collection.insert( 1 document of countryCode=1)
```

Upon execution, we have 1001 documents for each shard, so far so good.

Then we updated one document in shard0001 from countryCode=0 to countryCode=1 with the _id.  However, we ended up having 1002 records in JPN shard(shard0002) and 1001 record in USA shard(shard0001).  It appears that Mongos routes the update to shard0002 based on the new countryCode of 1 and executed the insert, and never made the update to the document in shard0001.  Hence now we have 2 documents of the same _id in two different shards.

We were expecting mongo would update the actual document in shard0001, then realized changing of countryCode from 0 to 1 will move that document to shard0002 instead.  Does Mongo do this automatically?

We know we can manually removing the document record from shard0001, do we really have to do this manually on our own?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/administer-shard-tags/#tag-a-shard-key-range) fro the keyrange asignment it have the notice: "To assign a tag to a range of shard keys use the sh.addTagRange() method when connected to a mongos instance. Any given shard key range may only have one assigned tag. You cannot overlap defined ranges, or tag the same range more than once.
"
The reason is in the backgroud mongodb will make splits to have chunks which are related only to that specific tags keyrange, and this way they able to move aroud according the tagging. So the alignment defined by the tags are ensured with two steps:

- The engine make splits to have chunks with key range exclusive for one shard tag
- The chunks in a balancing round will be aligned/moved around according the current shard-tag mapping.

<strike>I assume you checked the number of the docs from the side of the shards connecting there directly not through the mongos instance.  <strike>Weather it is a bug or not that</strike>  you ended up with the two docs but due to the shard key mapping you only able to access one of them through mongos due to the keyrange based alignment. If it not deleted automaticaly it is definitely a BUG and it should be addressed. I cannot check the jira from my current location. I will set up some test and get back to you with the results.</strike> That was due to the misunderstanding the described behaviour.

Based on your comments that you used save command to perform the update and this [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enforce-unique-keys-for-sharded-collections/#enforce-unique-keys-for-sharded-collections), the situation is when you save a document with

> {countrycode:0 _id:x}

combination which is a new one (you had previously a {countrycode:1 _id:x}) the _id is the same as for another document (the old one), and the new document reside on another shard (It is true due to the tagging is based on the countrycode), it will be inserted without a problem due to the uniqueness of the _id field is only ensured inside a given shard and collection. In different shards if _id is not the shard key, or not the first in a compound shard key, there is no garantie for the values of the _id field is globally unique. Basicly as it generated it is most likely will be unique, despite this situation when you on propose gave the same _id to preform update kind behaviour.

To give an answer for your question: if this situation for  you is not the expected you have to delete the old document and than create the new one, or more safely mark the old one as deleted (with a flag or so, and handle it on application side), and later look for deleted docs and really remove them  if needed (if you run out of space).

Comment: Hi Attish, thank you for the reply. To answer your questions: 1) we did not overlap the tag range for the sharding. As you see in our example: sh.addTagRange("test.persons", { countryCode: 0 }, { countryCode: 1 }, "USA"); country code of 0 is inclusive and country code of 1 is exclusive per our understanding for shard0001.  Therefore country code of 0 will goes to shard0001.  And country code of 1 will goes to shard0002.

2) in our update example, we did communicate with mongos, the router, not to the individual mongod.

Kindly let us know your finding.  Thank you.

Comment: clarification: from C# driver, we did not use update method as countryCode is part of the shard key and cannot be updated.  We use the save method (including the object id) and then mongos added to shard0002 and ignore the document in shard0001, hence now we have 2 copies of the document.  Are we doing the right steps for update?

Comment: Than it is clear check this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enforce-unique-keys-for-sharded-collections/#enforce-unique-keys-for-sharded-collections. , There is no garantie for the uniqueness of the _id field if it is not the shard key. It cannot be duplicated within one shard, but can have the same value on different shards. It is due to the collection on a given shard exists like an individual collection knows nothing about the whole picture, just containing all the data related to the shards chunks merged.